# Typescript: string is assignable to {} Type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is this:

```js
const test: {} = "test" // shouldn't this raise "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{}'." error?
console.log(test)
```

A valid Typescript code?
Just a moment ago this bit of code caused me to send wrong API calls, because I had something like this:

```
const getAPIData = async (id: string, filters: NetworkFilters | {} = {})
```

What I wanted to achieve is the `filters` prop to have default value of object with no properties, but by my mistake I passed string there and this broke my API calls. Why is it possible? It should raise an error.

Comment: Everything is an `object` in javascript.

Comment: You probably want to use `{[key: string]: unknown}` or `Record<string, unknown>` instead of `{}`

Comment: @zoran404 I have managed to get rid of this default `{}`, so now only `NetworkFilters` is acceptable. I was only wondering why it was assignable, but nevertheless thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sadly one of the edge cases in TS where it's probably a good idea to explain what `assignable` actually means.

`{}` is an object without properties, but as such, any object is assignable to it and `string` is not exception. (`string` also has methods f.e. `toLowerCase`).

If you for example declared `const test: { toLowerCase: () => string } = "test"`, you will also not get an error, because `toLowerCase` is a method of `string`.

If you said `const test: { notAStringMethod: () => string } = "test"`, then this fails, because `notAStringMethod` is not a method of `string` and thus isn't assignable.